# FTP authentification on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp, connection

I am trying to log into a ftp account with rails, but the authentification fails and i don't know why. My html page calls a method :

```
test(site.host,site.ftp_user,site.ftp_pw)
```

My helper defines this method :

```
def test(host_ip,user,pass)
ftp = Net::FTP.new(host_ip)
ftp.login('user','pass')
ftp.system
ftp.close
end
```

The information is working with FileZilla so the problem is somewhere else. Any idea ?

I'm getting confused with what should be between quotes or not. I mean site.ftp_user and site.ftp_pw are strings so i don't know why i have to use quotes. But if i don't use them, i get a gettaddrinfo error...

Here is the SocketError i get when removing the quotes :

```
 getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

Kinda lost here :/

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you want to remove the quote for `user` and `password` in your helper.

Then, what line is the getaddrinfo error on? maybe you can share it here.

Is it on the `ftp.system` line...if so it looks like system may not be the method call that you want.

If you want to open a file or something checkout the examples here http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/classes/Net/FTP.html

Comment: Here is the SocketError i get when removing the quotes :
      getaddrinfo: Name or service not known